# How to get user's browser name and append it as a class to <body> tag

Tags: php, concrete5

I'm doing a theme for Concret 5 and I'm not sure if there's already a similar solution to my problem from Concrete 5.

I want to append the user's browser name to my `<body>` so I can target them via css later

Example how the PHP should render the name to my body tag.

```
<body class="ie5" >
or
<body class="safari" >
```

**CSS Sample I'll use later**

```
body.ie div#id { background: #ccc }
body.safari div#id { font-size: 15px; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per your other requirement that wasn't asked before

for getting all browser's name

```
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $ub = '';
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $ub = "Internet Explorer";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $ub = "Mozilla Firefox";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $ub = "Apple Safari";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $ub = "Google Chrome";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Flock/i',$u_agent))
         {
            $ub = "Flock";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $ub = "Opera";
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
        {
            $ub = "Netscape";
        }
```

now you can show browser name

```
<body class="'. $ub ." >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // get the current browser name


// for safari 
if(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) // then check if the browser is safari 
        {
           echo "body.safari div#id { font-size: 15px; }"; // then apply your class here

        }

// for IE
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent))
        {
            echo "body.ie div#id { background: #ccc }";
        }
```

Comment: The remaining problem is that you wouldn't echo the css itself. It appears he want to know how to add the class to the body, not printing the css itself. Hopefully your if () is enough to get the idea though.

Comment: @JassiOberoi thanks for your answer. yours is very close to what i'm looking for. but few are missing. First, I wanted to target other browser too if possible all. Second, I just need it to be a variable to be echo something like this. <body class="'. $browser_name ." >

Comment: reason being I need it to be variable because I setup some few existing dynamic class being pulled from Concrete 5

Answer (score 0):

You could use the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

A sample value for Firefox is: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3`

Comment: If I append "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3", to my body tag that would be too long. I just wanted to use 'firefox' for targeting. so php should render somehting like this. <body class='firefox'>

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right. You need to parse that value and extract the information you need, as one of the other answers already explains.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']?>
```

Then in HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body class="<?php echo $agent?>">
    </body>
</html>
```

Then just setup your `CSS` for each browser name/type